# What is a Non-resident alien?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, resident

I left the US 3 years ago. Now I only occasionally visit the US for short visits. Am I still a non-resident alien?
I googled online and only found its definition in an "everything else" manner.
Does it mean that everyone who lives outside the US is a non-resident alien?
[image]

Comment: Are you a US citizen? Have you ever had a green card?

Answer (score 4):

> Does it mean that everyone who lives outside the US is a non-resident alien?

Everyone who is **neither** a US citizen **nor** a US permanent resident, **and** doesn't pass the [substantial presence test](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test).

Which is exactly what is in your diagram, wherever you got it from.

You can potentially live in the US and still qualify as a non-resident alien because some immigration statuses don't count towards the substantial presence test.

Comment: what about someone who never visited the US?

Comment: @Code42 what about them? The same rules apply.